# How should I convert Json to ResponseEntity<String>?

Tags: java, json

I have added Dependency for Gson in pom.xml

```
public ResponseEntity<String> findSearchInfo(@RequestParam String searchName)
 {
    ResponseEntity<String> response = gasRESTTemplate
                .getForEntity(uri,String.class);

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    response = gson.toJson(response);

return response;

}
```

uri is returning me a HashMap which I want to convert to JSON.So I have used Gson's toJson method.Now the problem is that method is returning me json but i am unable to assign it to response cause it's type is ResponseEntity which is compulsory.
So what should I do to return that json by response?
Because of this I am getting error

```
required: org.springfremwork.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String>
found: java.lang.String
```

I know return type is ResponseEntity
So How should I initialize that JSON to response variable.

Comment: I think you can pass any object as body in response entity,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using this constructor ([source](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html)) :

```
ResponseEntity(T body, MultiValueMap<String,String> headers, HttpStatus statusCode)

ResponseEntity<String> response = 
    new ResponseEntity(gson.toString(),
    new MultiValueMap(), 
    HttpStatus.OK);
```